# jQuery ajax data usability

Tags: jquery

Why doesn't this work?

```
var myData;

function getData()
{
    $.ajax(
        { 
            url: dataURL, 
            success: function(data)
            {
                myData = data;
            }
        }
    );
}

getData();
console.log(myData);
```

I'm scoping the variable correctly, but I can't use the data outside the function..

Comment: Can someone please edit their answer to use "async: false" , because that was the solution

Comment: I suggest you don't use `async: false`.  Using that will make the browser lock up until the AJAX call is done.  Best to let it run in the background and run the callback when its ready.

Comment: I understand what it does, and for this case it is the right solution. I'll go ahead and post the answer unless you'd like to post it and get the points.

Comment: You can go ahead and answer your own question.  I have enough points :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous.  It runs in the background while you code is running.  So, when you're calling `console.log(myData);`, the AJAX call isn't done yet, so the variable isn't set.

You should use the callback function to process the data, like so:

```
function getData(){
    $.ajax({ 
        url: dataURL, 
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}

getData();
```

Answer (score 2):

ajax works asynchronously ( you can make it be synchronous, but thats typically not what you want).  This means that the success callback you have defined only fires after the response comes from the server.  Put the log statement in the success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use `async: false`

```
var myData;

function getData()
{
    $.ajax(
        { 
            url: dataURL, 
            async: false, 
            success: function(data)
            {
                myData = data;
            }
        }
    );
}

getData();
console.log(myData);
```